# Positioning elements on container ExtJS

Tags: javascript, layout, extjs, containers

I have a combobox and a checkbox. I am adding them on a simple xtype: container and I want to position them in the middle of it with 20 pixel distance between them. I tried using many layouts for the container including hbox but it doesn't seem to work. Can you help?

```
var routingDisplaySets = Ext.create('widget.combobox', {
    fieldLabel: 'XXXX'
    });

var getVersionsRoutings = Ext.create('widget.checkbox', {
    boxLabel: ' XXXX', name: 'versionsCheckbox', id:'verCheckbox'});

var displayContainer = Ext.create('widget.container',{layout: {type: 'hbox', align: 'center'}, height:40, 
    items:[{xtype: routingDisplaySets},{xtype: getVersionsRoutings, x:20}]});
```

Here's what I'm getting: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2M4K7.jpg.
See how they are all cramped together? And they begin from the left side of the container... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.. Change your Hbox to **align: 'middle'** and **pack: 'center'**. Also remove the 'x' attribute on the checkbox and use **margin: 0 0 0 20** instead

```
    var routingDisplaySets = Ext.create('widget.combobox', {
        fieldLabel: 'XXXX'
    });

    var getVersionsRoutings = Ext.create('widget.checkbox', {
        boxLabel: ' XXXX',
        name: 'versionsCheckbox',
        id: 'verCheckbox',
        margin: '0 0 0 20'
    });

    var displayContainer = Ext.create('widget.container', {
        layout: {
            type: 'hbox',
            align: 'middle',
            pack: 'center'
        },
        height: 40,
        items: [{
            xtype: routingDisplaySets
        }, {
            xtype: getVersionsRoutings
        }]
    });
```

Comment: Excellent advice. First time I get an instant response on SO. Very good. I would vote up but still don't have rep :(